# Laravel search with relations

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have the following relations in my Laravel application

```
class Item extends Model 
{
    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
    }
}
```

and

```
class Category extends Model
{
    public function item()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Item');
    }
}
```

I want to implement search functionality so I have created the following Eloquent query:

```
$items = Item::where('item_type', '=', 'type1')
         ->where(function($query) use ($q) {
            $query->where('item_name','LIKE','%'.$q.'%')
                  ->orWhere('item_description','LIKE','%'.$q.'%');
         })
         ->paginate(10);
```

This is working as expected and returns the search results for 'q' based on the name and the description of the item.

As a next step, I would like to also search for the category_name. Because of the relation, I have the category_id stored in the Items table, but I would like to use the category_name in my Eloquent query.

Anyone could provide some help?

---

Based on feedback received, I tried:

**Suggestion 1:**

```
$items = Item::where('item_type', '=', 'type1')
         ->where(function($query) use ($q) {
           $query
             ->where('item_name', 'LIKE' ,'%'.$q.'%')
             ->orWhere('item_description', 'LIKE' ,'%'.$q.'%');
           })
           ->whereHas('category', function (Category $query) use ($q) {
              $query->where('category_name', $q);
           })
```

=> this gives following error message:

> Argument 1 passed to
>   App\Http\Controllers\ItemController::App\Http\Controllers{closure}()
>   must be an instance of App\Http\Controllers\App\Category, instance of
>   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder given

**Suggestion 2:**

```
$items = Item::where('item_type', '=', 'type1')
         ->where(function($query) use ($q) {
           $query
             ->where('item_name', 'LIKE' ,'%'.$q.'%')
             ->orWhere('item_description', 'LIKE' ,'%'.$q.'%');
           })
           ->whereHas('category', function ($query) use ($q) {
              $query->where('category_name', $q);
           })
```

=> this does not result any search result anymore (also not for item_name and item_description).

**Solution**

```
  $items = Item::where('item_type', '=', 'type1')
            ->where(function($query) use ($q) {
                $query
                 ->where('item_name', 'LIKE' ,'%'.$q.'%')
                 ->orWhere('item_description', 'LIKE' ,'%'.$q.'%');
              })
            ->orWhereHas('category', function ($query) use ($q) {
                 $query->where('category_name', $q);
              })
            ->sortable(['id' => 'desc'])
            ->paginate(10);
```

Comment: What you tried is not what I suggested though. I did not typehint `Category` in the whereHas closure.

Comment: Have you tried "orWhereHas" instead of "whereHas" in suggestion 2? As you don't want the result where both are equal to $q, rather than where one of them is equal to $q

Comment: Suggestion 2 in the original post is the variant which is not typehinted. But that also does not work.

Comment: So you want to search items that have a `Category` with a specific name. Is that right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you already described relation to `Category` in your `Item` model, you have to use just [`whereHas` method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence):

```php
$items = Item::where('item_type', '=', 'type1')
         ->where(function($query) use ($q) {
            $query->where('item_name','LIKE','%'.$q.'%')
                  ->orWhere('item_description','LIKE','%'.$q.'%');
         })
         ->orWhereHas('category', function ($query) use ($q) {
            $query->where('category_name', 'LIKE', "%$q%");
         })
         ->paginate(10);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Your suggestion does not seem to work. I edited the original post with error messages

Comment: Sorry, then just delete `Category` type-hinting from the query. I'll change my answer right now

Comment: @wiwa1978, I also updated my answer using `orWhereHas` method to save first condition

Comment: This works indeed, thanks. I'll accept this answer and update original post

Comment: Great! Was glad to help you

Answer (score 3):

You could add a `whereHas` and constrain it. For example:

```php
$items = Item::where('item_type', '=', 'type1')
    ->where(function($query) use ($q) {
        $query->where('item_name','LIKE','%'.$q.'%')
            ->orWhere('item_description','LIKE','%'.$q.'%');
    })
    ->whereHas('category', function($query) {
        $query->where('category_name', 'name');
    })
    ->paginate(10);
```

Comment: Thanks Mozammil. This seems correct also. Similar to @Sergey answer. Note: I just used the orWhereHas instead of whereHas. Thanks for your help!